# W2k3 AD Server spewing to 224.0.0.251.mdns

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, mdns

I'm looking at a tcpdump of my network and seeing floods of mdns packets from my W2k3 AD Server. :

```
03:28:30.655189 IP mydomainserver.local.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0*- [0q] 1/0/0 A 192.168.100.1 (40)
```

Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from installed software (which is a little concerning on a domain controller).

Check through Add/Remove Programs, and get rid of anything that shouldn't be there.

More info on multicast DNS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking#Apple.27s_protocol:_Multicast_DNS.2FDNS-SD).

Comment: As Shane says, this is Bonjour/mDNS. It's doing it because someone installed it, and you stop it by not installing stuff on your domain controllers unless you understand what it does.

Comment: Exactly right. Turned out to be a server product which uses Bonjour.